# change db server

Tags: database-connection, database-server

What is the safest way to change SharePoint 2013 on premise DB Server from one name to another - I have alredy migrated all dbs from the old to the new I just want Sharepoint to now point to the new and kill the old server

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Aliases on the SharePoint Farm (cliconfg.exe), then you could simply repoint your Alias to the new SQL instance.

If you are not using a SQL Alias and you are on port 1433, i.e. default instance, then:

1. Create a SQL Alias and "name" it the same as your old SQL Database Server. This needs to be done on Each SharePoint Server.
2. Point that Alias to the "New" SQL instance.

There are some caveats due to session state and usage, but you could fix those later.

Sometimes also you need to do this for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of aliases.

Comment: Hi I have tried the cliconfig method but when I go to regedit, the connection string for APPFabric 1.1 is still the old SQL server, and when I turn the old SQL server sharepoint is not responding, so it's clearly still connected. Also when I say Get-SPServer I see both the old and the new SQL Servers listed.... Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If I am not using any aliases, would this simple command work:

stsadm -o renameserver -oldservername <oldServerName> -newservername <newServerName>

??

Comment: Never used this stsadm. if you use what I suggested, you shouldn't see the new 'server' name in SharePoint. It  will be helpful to get into specifics without necessarily disclosing the names of your server.